# How to set a default value in p-dropdown in a reactive form angular

Tags: javascript, angular, dropdown, primeng

I have a reactive form that has some p-dropdown. During insertion, it is the user who chooses the desired item. When editing, the previously saved entry must be prevalued. I notice that the formcontrol contains the value, but the label of the p-dropdown is not valued.

```js
this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
  cuaa: new FormControl(this.currentRegistry?.cuaa ? this.currentRegistry.cuaa : null, Validators.required),
  ...
});
```

```html
<p-dropdown
  placeholder="Select an option.."
  id="cuaa"
  formControlName="cuaa"
  (onChange)="onSelect($event,'cuaa')"
  [options]="cuaaOptions"
  optionLabel="cuaa"
  optionValue="cuaa">
</p-dropdown>
```

cuaaOptions is such a structured object:

```js
[{ cuaa: string, denomination: string }]
```

Thank you